# drupal website admin login after hiding login block

Tags: drupal

I need to hide the user login panel from my drupal website. If I disable it from structure > blocks, how will I be able to log in to the admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the admin panel as `http://www.yourWebsite.com/?q=user`

This will show you the login panel, just enter the correct credentials and get going!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the login page on a Drupal site at `http://yoursite.example.com/user`, then display the admin pages using `http://yoursite.example.com/admin`.